# Left join in Hibernate "one to zero or one" mapping

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two tables as below:

```
Student: oneID (primary key), col1, col2, col3, subId, col4
Subject: subID (primary key), col1, col2
```

Every student will have exactly one or none of the subjects assigned.

So in the case: one subject assigned: subId in Student will have some value which maps to subID in Subject table

and in the case: 0 subject assigned: subId in Student will be null.

With above scenario, I have a left join query as below:

```
select st.col1, st.col2, su.col1, su.col2 from Student st left join Subject su on st.subId = su.subId where st.oneId = 'abc'
```

How to write the same exact query in Hibernate ?

```
select st.col1, st.col2, su.col1, su.col2 from Student st left join st.sub as su where st.oneId = 'abc'
```

Above query does not work and gives the below error:

```
"org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!"
```

What am I missing ?

In my java code I have kept both the tables independent. That is there is no relationship between the tables defined.

Persistence.xml is as below:

```
<persistence-unit name="myEntityManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">              
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>    
  <class>com.myPackage.Student</class>       
  <class>com.myPackage.Subject</class>   
</persistence-unit>
```

POJOs are as below:

Student

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ONEID")
private String oneId;

private Subject sub;

//other columns here

public void setSub(final Subject sub) {
    this.sub = sub;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Subject getSub() {
    return this.sub;
}
}
```

Subject

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SUBJECT")
public class Subject implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "SUBID")
private String subId;

//other columns here
}
```

Comment: My doubt is as you are projecting on subject attributes though subject is not available for a given student... it may lead to NullPointerException I think!

Comment: you need relation between student and subject to use join, also student doesn't look like having "subId"

Comment: @bestsss: I just have a property in Student table subId. When this is not null, we can join it with Subject table to fetch the subject details.

Comment: do you mean that there is only one subject per student? In any case you need either a `Subject` field in `Student` or `Collection<Subject>`, depending on the relation.

Comment: @bestsss: Yes. Either their is only one subject per student or no subject. If I have a Subject field in Student, what changes will I have to do in the two classes Subject and Student. Will there be any change in persistence.xml. I am extremely new to hibernate so would appreciate your guidance. thanks!

Comment: follow @yair's answer and read some tutorials, look at examples.

Comment: @bestsss: I have updated the question with the changes suggested in yair's answer.. but am still getting the same error..  The relationship is "one student to zero or one subject"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [this hibernate forum thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2392094), it's currently not possible in Hibernate to invoke left join on disassociated entities. There's also an [opened Hibernate issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-16) for it.

What you should do instead, is define a `one-to-one` or `one-to-many` relationship between `Student` and `Subject` ([one-to-one example](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-one-using-annotations-1.html), [many-to-one example](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-mapping-one-to-many-using-annotations-1.html)).

Then, try this HQL, assuming the reference in `Student` to its subjects is named `subjects`:

`select st.col1, st.col2, su.col1, su.col2 from Student st left join st.subjects su where st.oneId = 'abc'`

Comment: Thanks!! But the example you have shown clearly has one student having many phone numbers. But my example is either the student has one subject or no subjects.. how to do this ?

Comment: @NikunjChauhan - edited the answer to contain link to one-to-one example (note that the query should also change according to the reference name).

Comment: @yair: Sorry.. but its still not working.. I changed my classes and added annotation one to one as suggested.... Please note that my relationship between Student and Subject is "one to zero or one"... I am still getting "Path expected for join!" error...

Answer (score 0):

As I don't see any association between your models in mapping you can refer to [this](http://arnosoftwaredev.blogspot.com/2010/10/hibernate-joins-without-associations.html) link for your problem.  Or simply add association in your mapping i.e in student add many-to-one association for subject and modify your query as

```
select st.col1, st.col2, su.col1, su.col2 from Student st left outer join st.subject as su where st.oneId = 'abc' and st.subId = su.subId
```

Comment: Checked the link.. But not getting. I want left join because when subId is null in Student table, I still want the columns from Student table which I am fetching in my query.. I don't know how to achieve that..

Comment: Try this instead of join - select st.col1, st.col2, su.col1, su.col2 from Student st, Subject su where st.oneId = 'abc' and (st.subId = su.subId or st.subId is null)