# Joining two table in spring data JPA and Querying two table data from repository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, nhibernate-mapping, spring-data-jpa

I am using Sprind JPA, Spring 3.1.2(in future 3.2.3), Hibernate 4.1 final.
I am new to Sprind Data JPA. I have tow Table Release_date_type and Cache_media which entities are as follows :

ReleaseAirDate.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Release_date_type")
public class ReleaseDateType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer release_date_type_id;
    @Column
    private Integer sort_order;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Column
    private String data_source_type;
    @Column(nullable = true) 
    private Integer media_Id;
    @Column
    private String source_system; with getters and setters..
```

and CacheMedia as

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cache_Media")
public class CacheMedia {   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="code")
    private String code;
    @Column(name="POSITION")
    private Integer position;
    @Column(name="DESCRIPTION")
    private String media_Description; with setter and getters.
```

Now my repository interface is as follows :

```
public interface ReleaseDateTypeRepository extends CrudRepository<ReleaseDateType, Long>{ }
```

Now i want to write a method(Query) in `ReleaseDateTypeRepository` interface which can get all the data from `Release_Date_Type` table including appropriate `media_description` from Table 'Cache_Media' based on `media_id` of `Release_date_type` table.

So my select (SQL)query looks like

`SELECT * from Release_Date_Type r left join Cache_Media c on r.media_id=c.id`

I don't know how to map entities.
I tried so many thing but not luck.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining two table entities in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977130/joining-two-table-entities-in-spring-data-jpa)

Answer (score 1):

Its not the answer for joining via Hibernate, but alternatively you can create a view with your join and map the view to your objects

Comment: You map the view like a usual table, but you have to consider the object is readonly, and you need to compute a column with a unique value for the id.

You didnt mention your DBMS, but you can make a composite of CacheMedia.id and ReleasDatetype.Id or you can add something like the ROWID (Oracle)

Maybe this will help you further:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829848/to-map-a-database-view-with-no-primary-key-in-hibernate-xml-mapping

Comment: DB dependency will not allow me to create a View.I need to look around and see what i can do. Do you have any other alternative?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826080/hibernate-hql-selecting-objects-with-null-one-to-one-mapping-left-outer-join

and on this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784772/left-join-in-hibernate-one-to-zero-or-one-mapping